# How do I replace a $ in a Lua string?

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

How do you replace a dollar sign in Lua since it is a special character in pattern matching?

I've tried this:

```
string.gsub("$44,000.00", "$", "")
> "$44,000.00"
```

But all it does is add a blank at the end of the string. For example

```
string.gsub("$44,000.00", "$", "what")
> "$44,000.00what"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Knowing `$` is a special character is half way to the answer. Use `%` to escape magic characters:

```
string.gsub("$44,000.00", "%$", "what")
```